# Using multiple router defined in their own files in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node.js and express framework. I am getting an error when I am trying to go to the signuplogin route from my homepage route. I have also tried all the similar questions in the stackoveflow, but none of them have worked for me, so I thought of posting my own.

This is my **app.js**

```
var homepage = require('./routes/homepage');
var signupLogin = require('./routes/signuplogin');

var app = express();

app.use("/", homepage);
app.use("/signup-login", signupLogin);
```

This is my **homepage.js** in **routes directory**

```
var express = require('express');
var homepageRouter = express.Router();

/* GET Homepage. */
homepageRouter.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('../views/homepage/homepage.hbs');
});

module.exports = homepageRouter;
```

This is my **signup-login.js** in **routes directory**

```
var express = require('express');
var signupLoginRouter = express.Router();

/* GET Signup Login Page. */
signupLoginRouter.get("/signup-login", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = signupLoginRouter;
```

Well my `"/"` route works perfectly but it says 404 when I try to access `"/signup-login"` route.

I also changed the route to `"/signuplogin"` because I thought maybe it doesn't except the `"-"` character in the route. But that didn't work as well. Any solution/advice?

Comment: Did you specify the template engine you're using in your app.js? Seems you're using handlebars. So, seeing what is in your app.js might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done a mistake in your **signup-login.js** file. Correct the code with this -

```
/* GET Signup Login Page. */
signupLoginRouter.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
```

As per your code the actual url of signup page becomes to  "/signup-login/signup-login"

You don't need to add the singup-login url path again in your page. That is already referenced in your main router.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot. I would have never caught this. I can only accept this answer after 8 mins but I have upvoted it. I will try again after 8 mins to accept this answer